# dropzone js and android studio webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, dropzone

Actually I'm using dropzone js to upload files (images and videos) on my webserver. It works just fine.

Now I work on an android version of the app. To do so, I use the webview feature.

But dropzone doesn't seem to get on well with that. The file chooser is not triggered when I click on the dropzone area.
Does anyone have a solution to get through this ?